# Converting Shape file from GIS into a PPP using spatstat UK

Tags: r-sp, spatstat, r-maptools

I am trying to create a PPP in spatstat using my study area (a large polygon made up of individual polygons) from a shape file from GIS.

I have been following: Handling shapeles in the spatstat package
Adrian Baddeley, Rolf Turner and Ege Rubak
2022-11-08
spatstat version 3.0-2

#load packages
install.packages("spatstat")
library(spatstat)
install.packages("maptools")
library(maptools) #will get warning message about rgdal instead, stick with maptools
install.packages(sp)
library(sp)

#import shapefile
`UMshape1<-readShapeSpatial('F:/GIS/export_shape/Clipped_urban_matrix.shp')`

#check class
`class(UMshape1)`
#returned: [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

#following code from guidance to convert Objects of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
`UM1 <- as(UMshape1, "SpatialPolygons")` 
`UM1regions <- slot(UM1, "polygons") UM1regions <- lapply(UM1regions, function(x) { SpatialPolygons(list(x)) }) UM1windows <- lapply(UM1regions, as.owin)`

#checked class of each of these file types
`class(UM1)`
#"SpatialPolygons"
`class(UM1regions)`
#"list"
`class(UM1windows)`

## "list"

#from guidance 'The result is a list of objects of class owin. Often it would make sense to convert this to a tessellation object, by typing':
#so I enter the code for my data
`teUM1 <-tess(tiles = UM1windows)`

This last command (tess) has now been running for 48 hours (red stop box). I did not created a progress bar.

Is this the right thing to do so that I can then created my owin study area? So that I can then create a PPP in spatstat?

Comment: Can you share the data? Are there very many polygons and do they have complex shapes?

Answer (score 1):

If the desired result is a single window of class `owin` to use as the window for your point pattern, then you don't need a tessellation. Instead of `teUM1 <-tess(tiles = UM1windows)` you should probably do `teWin <- union.owin(as.solist(UM1windows))`.

If you do really need a tessellation (which would keep each of the windows separate for further use) then you could call `tess(tiles=UM1windows, check=FALSE)`. The long computation time is caused by the fact that the code is checking whether each window overlaps any of the other windows. This check is disabled if you set `check=FALSE`.

Comment: Thank You for this @Adrian. I will be honest and say I am not sure if I need a tessellation. I am converting a shape file from GIS into a study area to assign my window (1623 Km2). Due to the fact its a shape file from GIS its pulled over lots of polygons making up my study area. Its the study area as a whole that I need to set up as my window owin.

Comment: I will run the new code to set up owin for my ppp using teWin <- union.owin(as.solist(UM1windows)). Can I just then run standard ppp code using new teWin as owin? Or would I need:  ppp(x, y, poly) for polygonal window? I apologise for my lack of technical ability using spatstat